# UITextField unresponsive to opening UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I am using a UIPickerView as the first responder of a UITextField. I set this as shows:

```
var myPickerView = UIPickerView()
myTextField.inputView = myPickerView
```

I was not having issues with this until I added a UITapGestureRecognizer (that would allow me to click outside of the picker view to dismiss it) to the view like so:

```
let dismissUnitPickerGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hidePicker")
dismissUnitPickerGesture.delegate = self
dismissUnitPickerGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

hidePicker func:

```
@IBAction func hidePicker(){
    myTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    //I don't think this code is relevant to the problem, but I included it just in case
    if materialSelectedOption == "Aluminum Cans" {
        amountTextField.placeholder = "Number of Cans"
        unitCell.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Now it takes up to five clicks on the UITextField on the simulator to open the picker view, which is frustrating and obviously not good for an app. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the tap gesture, but I could be wrong.

If there are any other questions you guys have please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to just detect that a tap is registered outside the pickerView  and hide it is kind of wrong!
you can use the `touchesBegan` function and call `self.view.endEditing(true)` like so:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        //or use textField.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but could help point out how I would implement this? I haven't used anything of the sort before.

Comment: Paste it in your viewController!

Comment: Alright, I tried that and disable the UITapGestureRecognizer stuff, but now it doesn't dismiss the UIPickerView when I tap outside of it, which is what I need

Comment: that should be working just fine! you should be doing something wrong ! could you paste your code or just make sure that you completely remove the code fot the `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: I'm using it like you said, and it's not working. You said I didn't need to do anything else, so your answer isn't working for me.

Comment: you can still add a view on top of the pickerView with a button "done"! let me know if you need help on this solution

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to add tool bar with "Done" and "Clear" items instead gesture.
The following code you can use:

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(sender: UITextField) {{
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.myTextField.frame.size.height/6, self.myTextField.frame.size.width, 40.0))
        toolBar.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.myTextField.frame.size.width/2, y: self.myTextField.frame.size.height-20.0) 
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent       
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        let defaultButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(CustomTimePickerTextView.clearTime(_:)))   
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: #selector(CustomTimePickerTextView.donePressed(_:)))    
        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let textButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: self.placeholder, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        toolBar.setItems([defaultButton,flexSpace,textButton,flexSpace,doneButton], animated: true)

        self.myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    func clearTime(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
        //
    }

    func donePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.myTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    }
```

Comment: I like this idea, and I tried to use your code but it just added extra space above my picker view options and didn't show anything

Comment: I solved it by placing your code in my `viewDidLoad` method. I apologize but I don't think I will accept your answer because @Med Abida already directed me to this idea below, and I had to refer to other Stack Overflow questions to get it working anyway. Sorry :/